# Вычислить максимальное и минимальное значение для всех типов числовых переменных

Tags: c

Важно сделать это на основании арифметических действий(нельзя использовать `sizeof` и библиотеку `limits.h`)
нужно сделать это для `char` (`signed/unsigned`) , `int` (`signed/unsighed`), `short` (`signed/unsigned`), `long` (`signed/unsigned`)

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
#include<conio.h>
main(){
int a,b,i,k;
a=2;
b=2;
i=1;
k=2;
while(a<=b){
    a=pow(a,i);
    b=pow(b,k);
    i=i+1;
    k=k+1;

}
fflush(stdin);
a=a-1;
    printf("%d",a);
    _getch();
}
```

Это только часть кода, да и она не работает , не доходит до нужного максимального значения , ломается на 24 степени , а ведь нужно до 31 .

Comment: Для моделирования запрещенного `sizeof` двигайте единичку и сравнивайте новое значение с предыдущим... (а вообще-то, конечно, бредовое задание)

Comment: Использовать `pow()` для целочисленных типов (и вообще, что-то из `math.h`) - плохая идея. Не говоря уж о том, что само по себе возведение в степень для решения данной задачи... нет, не могу сформулировать, в таких сферах не витаю :) Может, вы с побитовым сдвигом перепутали? Ну а вообще тупое `++` уже решает задачу.

Comment: printf("%d\n", (unsigned typename)(0-1)) вполне пригодно для получения максимального значения

Comment: У вас что-то не то  с `a=pow(a,i);`. При увеличивающемся `i` вы возводите исходную двойку в квадрат, потом получившуюся четвёрку в куб и т. д. Разве не надо последовательно возводить исходное число в одну и ту же степень двойки (`a=pow(a,2);`)?

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов , если честно , то я полный нуб и не понимаю, что значит (unsigned typename)(0-1)

Comment: @PinkTux , можете показать как?

Comment: @Arhad, и ведь действительно , как это можно исправить?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Так](https://ideone.com/PIjfhJ) не годится?

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    {
        long max = 0;
        for(long cur = 1;cur > max; cur = (cur<<1) + 1)
            max = cur;
        printf("long max = %d\n",max);
    }
    {
        char max = 0;
        for(char cur = 1;cur > max; cur = (cur<<1) + 1)
            max = cur;
        printf("char max = %d\n",max);
    }
    {
        unsigned char max = 0;
        for(unsigned char cur = 1;cur > max; cur = (cur<<1) + 1)
            max = cur;
        printf("unsigned char max = %d\n",max);
    }
}
```

Формально со знаковыми не совсем корректно - потому что используем битовое представление в виде дополнения до 2, да и переполнение знаковое вроде как UB...

Comment: а что значит cur

Comment: cur = (cur<<1) + 1;  как понять эту запись?

Comment: long cur = 1;; а это как расшифровать?

Comment: Временная переменная в цикле, только и всего. Условие выхода - в теле цикла, отсюда почти пустой заголовок. `cur = (cur<<1)+1;` - сдвиг влево на один бит и установка младшего бита равным 1. Просто ищем максимальное число вида 111...111 в двоичном представлении.

Comment: Да, с утра голова никакая была... Вот, то же, но короче записанное :)

Answer (score 1):

Если вам нужно считать значения, меняя тип данных в коде программы, то возможен такой вариант (пример для максимума):

```
int a = 1; //попробуйте здесь поменять на short, long long...
while (a>0)
{
    a <<= 1;
}
a--;
printf("%d",a); //ну если тут будет, например, long long, то не забудьте поменять
```

Привожу свой вариант, который реализован в виде функций. Правда код на С++. Не знаю, есть ли в Си шаблоны, но если нет, тогда придется перегружать функции

```
template <class T>
int size_of(T a)
{
    a = 1;
    int count = 0;
    while (a)
    {
        a <<= 1;
        count++;
    }
    return count / 8;
}

template <class T>
bool isUnsigned(T a)
{
    a = -1;
    return 1 < a;
}

template <class T>
T maxSize(T a)
{
    int n = size_of(a) * 8 - 1 + isUnsigned(a);
    a = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) a <<= 1;
    return a-1;
}

template <class T>
T minSize(T a)
{
    bool u = isUnsigned(a);
    if (u) return 0;
    int n = size_of(a) * 8 - 1 + u;
    a = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) a <<= 1;
    return a;
}
```

Main для тестировки:

```
int main()
{
    cout << (int)maxSize((char)1) << endl;
    cout << (int)maxSize((unsigned char)1) << endl;
    cout << maxSize((short)1) << endl;
    cout << maxSize((unsigned short)1) << endl;
    cout << maxSize(1) << endl;
    cout << maxSize(1u) << endl;
    cout << maxSize(1ll) << endl;
    cout << maxSize(1ull) << endl << endl;
    cout << (int)minSize((char)1) << endl;
    cout << (int)minSize((unsigned char)1) << endl;
    cout << minSize((short)1) << endl;
    cout << minSize((unsigned short)1) << endl;
    cout << minSize(1) << endl;
    cout << minSize(1u) << endl;
    cout << minSize(1ll) << endl;
    cout << minSize(1ull) << endl;
}
```

Результат работы:

```
127
255
32767
65535
2147483647
4294967295
9223372036854775807
18446744073709551615

-128
0
-32768
0
-2147483648
0
-9223372036854775808
0
```

Comment: Спасибо, что постарались помочь, но мне пока далеко до си++ .Но плюсик все равно могу поставить

Comment: @Elvin, посмотрите изменение ответа (верхнюю часть). Может, этот вариант вас устроит больше

Comment: @Pasha ,  a <<= 1 что это значит

Comment: @Elvin, это краткая запись выражения a = a << 1; << - это операция побитового сдвига. Например, a = 10111, тогда a << 1 будет равно 01110